# Android NDK: cannot launch javah

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, javah

I'm trying to set javah command in External Tools in Android Studio but I get

> IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name:
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program

Here are my settings in External Tools in Android Studio:

> Program: $JDKPath$\bin\javah.exe
>
> Parameters: -classpath $Classpath$ -v-cpp $FileClass$
>
> Working directory: $ProjectFileDir$\app\src\main\cpp

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found by myself. Here are the correct parameters:

> Parameters: -classpath $ProjectFileDir$\app\src\main\java $FileClass$